# bleak.exc.BleakError: Descriptor None was not found

Tags: python, bluetooth, kivy, kivymd

### bleak.exc.BleakError: Descriptor None was not found!

able to write easily using bleak but reaading from bleak using python is a headache!! Anyone has any ideas as to how to read data using bleak would be helpful or how to fix this issue.

```
def scan1(self):
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(self.begin_scan1()) ## calling function

async def begin_scan1(self):

    def callback2(sender, data):
        print(sender, data, 'llllll')
        self.val1 = data

    a = []
    scanned_devices = await bleak.BleakScanner.discover(1)

    if len(scanned_devices) == 0:
        print("NO DEVICES")
    scanned_devices.sort(key=lambda device: -device.rssi)
    for device in scanned_devices:
        device1 = f"{device.name}"
        print(device1)
        if device1 == "Bluno":
            # try:

            async with bleak.BleakClient(device) as client:
                print('rr')
                paired = client.pair(protection_level=2)
                print(f"Paired: {paired}")
                COLOR_CHARACTERISTIC = "0000dfb1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
                 

                uu = '1'
                write_value = bytearray([int(uu)])
                await client.write_gatt_char(COLOR_CHARACTERISTIC, write_value)
                await asyncio.sleep(4.0)
                print('www')
                await client.start_notify(COLOR_CHARACTERISTIC, callback2) ## getting error 
                print('wwee')

                await asyncio.sleep(10.0)
                print('rrrq')
                await client.stop_notify(COLOR_CHARACTERISTIC)
```

Comment: yes  characteristic support notifications

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes I did try to see the data with other apps like nrf connect , the data was coming correct in those. No there is no reason for client.pair or connect even without those the code is giving the same issue, just that reading the data is giving issues be in read_gatt_char(giving 0x01 always for output  or start_notify which is giving the above issue. Any idea how to solve it?